# Does Microsoft SQL 2017 have TDE function?

Tags: sql-server, redhat

I'm aware that ms sql 2016 enterprise has TDE function but there is nowhere to be found that if 2017 for Linux has similar functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TDE is available on the Linux version. The [Security limitations for SQL Server on Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-security-overview) are listed, and the [*Transparent Data Encryption* (TDE)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption-tde) isn't among them, while it is listed in the [SQL Security Center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/security-center-for-sql-server-database-engine-and-azure-sql-database) as being available in both *SQL Server* and *SQL Database* (Azure) ever since SQL Server 2008.

Also, the [Walkthrough for the security features of SQL Server on Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-security-get-started) has a section for Enabling Transparent Data Encryption. (What's the "nowhere to be found"? It's on the *Get Started* guide.)